# Javascript to get value between two characters

Tags: javascript, split, substring

I am trying to get values between two characters. 
In the below myStr , I want to fetch "myemail"

```
            var myStr = "0#.f|membership|**myemail**@comp.com";
            var subStrVal = myStr.match("membership|(.*)@");
            alert(subStrVal[1]);
```

The code is not behaving as expected.
Can anyone correct me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may consider using `"membership\\|\\*{2}(.*)\\*{2}@"` as regex. Also consider the greediness to use based on the problem you are solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, the bar `|` is magic.  You have to escape it.:

```
var myStr = "0#.f|membership|**myemail**@comp.com";
myStr.match(/membership\|(.*)@/);
```

Comment: You may find it easier to open Firebug on Firefox or Dev Tools on Chrome and play around with the simplest cases.  Trying to parse `"a|b"` for the "b" would make the problem obvious.

Comment: Yes .. Dev Tools is a great way to troubleshoot and fix issues if any. Thank You!